# cabal test not finding module

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to get `cabal test` to run my HUnit test, without much luck. The problem is that it can't find one of my test modules — how do I fix this?

`cabal configure --enable-tests && cabal build && cabal test` fails with

```
tests/HUnit/Test.hs:4:18:
    Could not find module `AmazonTest'
```

**/tests/HUnit**

AmazonTest.hs

```
module AmazonTest where

import Test.HUnit
import Lib.Amazon

tests = TestList [ "test sayHello" ~: "Hell!" ~=? sayHello ]
```

Test.hs

```
module Main where

import Test.HUnit
import qualified AmazonTest as Amazon

main = runTestTT Amazon.tests
```

**\Lib\Amazon.hs**

```
module Lib.Amazon where

sayHello :: String
sayHello = "Hello!"
```

**test part of my .cabal file**

```
test-suite test
    type:              exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is:           tests/HUnit/Test.hs
    hs-source-dirs:    .
    ghc-options:       -Wall

    build-depends: base
                 , myapp
                 , yesod-test >= 0.3 && < 0.4
                 , yesod-default
                 , yesod-core
                 , persistent
                 , persistent-postgresql
                 , resourcet
                 , monad-logger
                 , HUnit
                 , text
```

Comment: Add `tests/HUnit` to `hs-source-dirs`.

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov Thanks again; it works now. I expected it to recursively search hs-source-dirs. Can you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `tests/HUnit` to `hs-source-dirs`. `hs-source-dirs` are not searched recursively.